# (R) Error in optim - attempt to apply non-function, when function is defined

Tags: r, syntax-error, cross-validation

not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to get a cross-validation score for a mixture-of-two-gammas model.

```
llikGammaMix2 = function(param, x) {
  if (any(param < 0) || param["p1"] > 1) {
    return(-Inf)
  } else {
    return(sum(log(
      dgamma(x, shape = param["k1"], scale = param["theta1"]) *
        param["p1"] + dgamma(x, shape = param["k2"], scale = param["theta2"]) *
        1
      (1 - param["p1"])
    )))
  }
}

initialParams = list(
  theta1 = 1,
  k1 = 1.1,
  p1 = 0.5,
  theta2 = 10,
  k2 = 2
)

for (i in 1:nrow(cichlids)) {
  SWS1_training <- cichlids$SWS1 - cichlids$SWS1[i]
  SWS1_test <- cichlids$SWS1[i]
  MLE_training2 <-
    optim(
      par = initialParams,
      fn = llikGammaMix2,
      x = SWS1_training,
      control = list(fnscale = -1)
    )$par
  LL_test2 <-
    optim(
      par = MLE_training2,
      fn = llikGammaMix2,
      x = SWS1_test,
      control = list(fnscale = -1)
    )$value
}
print(LL_test2)
```

This runs until it gets to the first `optim()`, then spits out `Error in fn(par, ...) : attempt to apply non-function`.

My first thought was a silly spelling error somewhere, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you give an example of `cichlids`? I'm trying to run the code and I can't replicate this issue without that object.

Comment: It's a data frame, 94 rows (observations) by 13 columns (variables) - `SWS1` is a numeric variable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is in the return statement. It's unclear if you meant to multiply or add the last quantity `(1 - param["p1"]))))` to the return value. Based on being a mixture, I'm guessing you mean for it to be multiplied. Instead it just hangs at the end which throws issues for the function:

```
    return(sum(log(dgamma(x, shape = param["k1"], scale = param["theta1"]) *
                     param["p1"] + 
                   dgamma(x, shape = param["k2"], scale = param["theta2"]) *
                     (1 - param["p1"])))) ## ISSUE HERE: Is this what you meant?
```

There could be other issues with the code. I would double check that the function you are optimizing is what you think it ought to be.  It's also hard to tell unless you give a reproducible example we might be able to use. Try to clear up the above issue and let us know if there are still problems.